# Angular 5 create and edit Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have an Angular 5 app with a simple Form to enter data and a list next to it to manipulate the entries.

When the data is ready I have a button which should create a google spreadsheet locally and send it to google drive.

I tried it with [google-apps-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-apps-script) which has [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script) but when importing the types to a module or service I get:

```
ERROR in src/app/common.service.ts(3,27): error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/myuser/Documents/dev/apps/project-booking/node_modules/@types/google-apps-script/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

I do the Import like this:

```
import {GoogleAppsScripts} from '@types/google-apps-script';
```

or like this:

```
import {SpreadsheetApp} from '@types/google-apps-script';
```

but in both cases I get the above error.
Is something wrong with my imports or is this library broken?

Comment: I'm not sure about creating a google spreadsheet locally. Isn't it the case the google sheets can only be created in google drive. You can download it locally, but as an excel CSV etc, not as an actually google sheet.

Comment: [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-apps-script) gives you a command line interface which I would like to utilize in my Angular app. I think technically those files are created on Google Drive, hence the Authentication step. But I'm already struggling at the import of the libraries.